# What is the proper location for test classes in a multi module project?

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, junit

Here is my overall goal: I want a Spring Boot REST API.  Ultimately, this will have an Angular front end.  The REST API will have a number of JPA Entities.  I need to be able to use those entities in a Jasper Reports Server as well as my REST API.  To do that, I'm thinking that the best approach is a multi-module Maven project.  My setup would then look like this:

```
- Project
--Web App
--Utilities
--HumanResources
--Sales
--etc.
```

where Web App, Utilities, HumanResources, Sales, etc. are modules.  I can use Utilities in the Web App, but the build will also produce a separate jar that I can use in Jasper (at least that is my hope).

Ideally, I would like to have only one application.properties file for Spring Boot.  However, as far as I can see, if I put the application.properties file in the Web App module, then all my unit tests (at least anything requiring a database connection) for Utilities, Sales, etc. would need to be in Web App. That doesn't seem ideal either, but if I put all the tests in their own module, it seems that I will need an application.properties file in each module, which also seems confusing.

Is my approach valid, or is there a better way?  How can I do testing on each module but still have everything tied together in an easy way?

Thanks!

Comment: Each module should have its own test classes.

Comment: @araknoid Then should I just duplicate the application.properties file in every module, or is there a way around that?

Comment: You can put all the configurations/common part in a common module that will hold everything that needs to be shared between the modules without duplicating them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, each module should have its own test classes in order to keep the test classes within the same module of the code tested by them. It would be a really bad idea to have the test classes in another module. In fact, what happens if you modify something in a module that breaks the tests but you forgot in which module the test classes were placed? You won't have any notification at compile time unless you compile the other module(s).

Second, if you need to have common configurations/files/classes, you can put all them in a common module that will hold everything that needs to be shared between the modules without duplicating them. Therefore each module will declare the common module as a dependency.